# Copy column in one table to another column in another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have three tables and there respective columns

tReferences:

```
 PK_Reference
 FK_ReferenceType
 ReferenceValue
 thePKofMain_FK
```

tReferencesTypes:

```
 PK_ReferenceType
 ReferenceName
```

tMain:

```
 PK_Main
 FirstReferenceValue
 SecondReferenceValue
 ThirdReferenceValue
```

Three references have become important enough that they are going to have to go to the tMain table. Let's say the PK of the three references from tReferenceTypes are 321, 654, and 987. I need to copy the references values from tReference to tMain table where each reference has their own columns now, but I have to make sure that I am adding the value from tReference to the correct PK_Main which is suppose to be the same value as the thePKofMain_FK in tReference table, and that I amtReferenceType PK.

I need something like this...

```
UPDATE tMain
SET 
tMain.FirstReferenceValue = (SELECT ReferenceValue FROM tReference WHERE FK_referenceType =321)
FROM  tReference 
WHERE tReference. thePKofMain_FK = tMain.PK_Main
```

But I get this messages which makes sense:

> Sub query returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   sub query follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the sub query is used
>   as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

```
UPDATE tMain
SET 
tMain.FirstReferenceValue = (SELECT ReferenceValue FROM tReference
JOIN tReference on tReference.thePKofMain_FK = tMain.PK_Main
WHERE FK_referenceType =9001649
WHERE FK_referenceType =321)
FROM  tReference 
WHERE tReference. thePKofMain_FK = tMain.PK_Main
```

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 18. Ambiguous column name
>   'FK_referenceType'. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15. Ambiguous
>   column name 'ReferenceValue'.

OR should I look into doing it in C#?

Comment: Which part of error message is not clear?  You have ambiguous column.

Comment: The error message is clear, just added them in there just for examples of things I tried. I am still stuck on trying to achieve what I need.

Comment: @elquesogrand share sample data

Comment: **tReferences**:

PK_Reference,
 123
 456
 789

FK_ReferenceType,
 321
 654
 987
ReferenceValue,
 111
 a
 1
thePKofMain_FK
 147
 258
 369
**tReferencesTypes**:

PK_ReferenceType,
 321
 654
 987
ReferenceName
 FirstReferenceValue
 SecondReferenceValue
 ThirdReferenceValue
**tMain**:

PK_Main,
 147
 258
 369
FirstReferenceValue,
111
SecondReferenceValue,
a
ThirdReferenceValue
1

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin 
Sorry that is very ugly... but if you put it back into notepad it'll show the data and how the tables connect.

Answer (score 0):

Some example data:

**tReferences:**

PK_Reference

```
 123    
 456    
 789
```

FK_ReferenceType:

```
 321    
 654   
 987
```

ReferenceValue

```
 111    
 a    
 1
```

-------------- why I got the first error messages since some reference values are the same

```
 111
 c
 2
```

thePKofMain_FK

```
 147    
 258    
 369
```

**tReferencesTypes:**

PK_ReferenceType

```
 321    
 654    
 987
```

ReferenceName:

```
FirstReferenceValue     
SecondReferenceValue    
ThirdReferenceValue
```

**tMain:**

PK_Main:

```
 147    
 258    
 369
```

FirstReferenceValue:

```
Empty
```

SecondReferenceValue:

```
Empty
```

ThirdReferenceValue:

```
Empty
```

There is duplicates of ReferenceValues that why the first sql query doesn't work, but even if there are duplicates of the same referenceValue I still need to copy it over to the new table

The second query it accidently typed in WHERE FK_referenceType =9001649 when I was trying to post the question.

Comment: Edit the question to add this data to make sure that anyone who get in here will read it

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot to get the tMain values

```
INSERT tMain (PK_Main, FirstReferenceValue, SecondReferenceValue, ThirdReferenceValue)
SELECT P.thePKofMain_FK, P.[321], P.[654], P.[987]
FROM (
    SELECT FK_ReferenceType, ReferenceValue, thePKofMain_FK
    FROM tReference
) T
PIVOT (
    MAX(ReferenceValue) FOR FK_ReferenceType IN ([321], [654], [987])
) P
```